# Performance of Anonymous PL/SQL Block versus Native SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, locking

I have a SQL statement which gives significantly different performance when executed inside PL/SQL block.

The SQL is extremely simple.

```
INSERT into Existing_Table SELECT col1,col2... from Other_table where rownum < 100000
```

When this is executed as SQL, it comes back almost immediately.

But when executed inside Anonymous PL/SQL block, it hangs forever:

```
begin
    INSERT into Existing_Table SELECT col1, col2... from Other_table where rownum < 100000;
end;
/
```

Comment: one reason that comes to mind, is being anonymous. The performance might change if you place that inside a procedure, and call it a couple of times. But regarding you pure sql operation, the true way to test that, is to flush all memory cache. You may have great performance, because other users ( or yourself) have been accessing those tables, and that may be misleading.

Comment: Might be better off posting this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For something this simple, there should be no difference. The only thing that I can think of that would do this (and it's irrelavant to being PL/SQL) is that you have a unique index on EXISTING_TABLE; you run the first SQL without committing, and then run the PL/SQL from another session. The 2nd session is waiting until commit before it can determine if you have a duplicate in your index...

Comment: I would do some standard troubleshooting to compare the two versions. What is the slow one waiting on, and are the execution plans the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when executed inside Anonymous PL/SQL block, it hangs forever:

I'm guessing two things:

1. Your table (Existing_Table) has a constraint on one of the columns you're using in the insert statement.
2. You forgot to issue a commit in between your execution of the SQL statement and the PL/SQL Anonymous Block.

Executing your statement in SQL and PL/SQL shouldn't have a difference in performance. It should've executed in almost the same amount of time.
But due to the Constraint or the Commit, it's being blocked because the row is locked.

Here's an example.

In Session 1, Create two Tables. One with a Constraint, and one without:

```
create table Existing_Table 
(
  existing_column number primary key
);

create table Existing_Table_2
(
  existing_column number
);
```

On the same session, execute the following SQL Statement:

```
insert into Existing_Table (existing_column) values (1);
```

Result:

```
1 row inserted.
```

On Another (Session 2), Execute the following PL/SQL Anonymous Block:

```
begin
  insert into Existing_Table (existing_column) values (1);
end;
```

This will hang until you issue a commit in Session 1.

This is because Session 1 has "reserved" the value of "1" for existing_column and will be "saved" when you issue a commit.
Session 2 is merely waiting for Session 1 to Commit or Rollback the Insert.

Now, when I go back to Session 1 and issue a commit, the row will be unlocked.
However, Session 2 will result into an Error because of the Integrity Constraint Violation:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
begin
  insert into Existing_Table (existing_column) values (1);
end;
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (APPS.SYS_C001730810) violated
ORA-06512: at line 2
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

Now, Another example of a table WITHOUT a constraint.

Run the below SQL in Session 3 without a commit:

```
insert into Existing_Table_2 (existing_column) values (1);
```

Result:

```
1 row inserted.
```

Run the same SQL inside an Anonymous PL/SQL Block in Session 4:

```
begin
  insert into Existing_Table_2 (existing_column) values (1);
end;
```

Result:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

It inserted fine even without a commit in session 1 because there wasn't any constraints being violated.

Just note that none of the data in Session 3 and 4 will be actually saved in the Database until you issue a commit.

Check out other articles about Session Blocking here:

[Tracking Oracle blocking sessions](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tracking_oracle_blocking_sessions.htm)

[Find blocking sessions](https://www.oraclerecipes.com/monitoring/find-blocking-sessions/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate the problem but was unable to. As correctly pointed out by others, the SQL was simple enough and executing it as either SQL or anon PL/SQL should not have made the difference.

The only thing comes to mind is that I may have failed to notice whether I had another session trying a DML without a COMMIT/ROLLBACK; and that might have caused the hang. So scenario mentioned by BobC and Migs Isip may be relevant here. Thanks all.

Comment: if the answers/comment mentioned has helped you, kindly accept the answer by clicking on the check mark so that others may be guided as well.